# Laravel Eloquent: How to use whereDate with Between?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel 5.5, I need to form a query where only date part of a datetime column should be matched, equivalent of `date(date_col)='2018-01-01'` kind of thing. How do I achieve this in Eloquent way? `WhereDate()` returns date part but is there some way to merge both?

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For merging whereDate and between you can use something like this:

```
User::whereBetween(DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'), array($from_date, $to_date))->get();
```

sql :

```
select * from `users` where DATE(created_at) between '2018-02-01' and '2018-02-06'
```

Comment: this is the right answer for whereBetween

Answer (score 0):

You can use Carbon:

```
$q->whereDate('date_col', '=', Carbon::parse($date)->toDateString());
```

`whereDate` should work too, pass in the value as the 2nd parameter

```
->whereDate('date_col', '2018-02-06')
```

Comment: That was not my original question.