# laravel query between two dates from two date columns database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a database `events` and it has 2 dates column named `date_from` which refers to start date and `date_to` refers to end date. The column `event_date` is when is the event posted. My question is how can I query this using the eloquent? I tried this code but it returns me an error. `Type error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`

Query

```
  $events = Event::where('school_id', '=', Auth::user()->school_id)
                      ->where('status', '=', 1)
                      ->where('active', '=', 1)
                      ->whereRaw("group_id in('$role', '0')")
                      ->whereBetween("date_from", "date_to" )
                      ->limit(2)
                      ->get();
```

Db structure

```
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(191)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| content     | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| group_id    | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| event_date  | date             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date_from   | date             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date_to     | date             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| time_from   | time             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| time_to     | time             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| event_place | varchar(191)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| image       | varchar(191)     | NO   |     |         |                |
| school_id   | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| smsnotify   | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| appnotify   | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| status      | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| active      | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| updated_by  | varchar(191)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at  | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| users_id    | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Eloquent: How to use whereDate with Between?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48657338/laravel-eloquent-how-to-use-wheredate-with-between)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved it by using two `whereRaw` statements

`$now = Carbon::now()->toDateString();`

```
$events = Event::where('school_id', '=', Auth::user()->school_id)
                      ->where('status', '=', 1)
                      ->where('active', '=', 1)
                      ->whereRaw("group_id in('$role', '0')")
                      ->whereRaw("date_from <=  date('$now')")
                      ->whereRaw("date_to >=  date('$now')")
                      ->limit(2)
                      ->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

- I have tried this and it's working for me a two-column date range
  with two between dates

  ```
    | # | name    | from_date  | to_date    |
    | ----------- | ---------  | ---------- |-
    | 1 | Kishor  | 2021-05-17 | 2021-05-25 |
    | 2 | Martin  | 2021-05-24 | 2021-05-24 |


    select * from TableName  (`date_to` >= $from_date and `date_from` <= $to_date) 

    $query->where(function($query) use ($from, $to){
           $query->where('date_to', '>=', $from)
              ->where('date_from', '<=', $to);
           });
  ```

Answer (score 1):

```
Use whereColumn of laravel query builder like this.

$events = Event::where('school_id', '=', Auth::user()->school_id)
                      ->where('status', 1)
                      ->where('active', 1)
                      ->whereRaw("group_id in('$role', '0')")
                       ->whereColumn([ ['date_from', '>=', 'event_date'], ['date_to', '<=', 'event_date'] ]);
                      ->limit(2)
                      ->get();
```

Comment: something similar with mine